# Local Private MSMQ to remote Private queue

Tags: windows, powershell, msmq

I'm trying to move a message from my local private queue to a remote queue.
I did "Move" from my local queue and gave destination as "\private$\" and got the error

```
"Failed to move message from <my local queue name> to <remote queue name> because the target queue or subqueue is invalid"
```

Also tried with the remote queue name as "FORMATNAME:DIRECT=OS:\private$\" and got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?
If it can be done using Powershell then an example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it you're not specifying the remote address or queue name, you need to use this format:

```
FORMATNAME:DIRECT=ComputerAddress\PRIVATE$\PrivateQueueName
```

If you need to be more specific about how to connect, use

```
FORMATNAME:DIRECT=TCP:123.45.67.89\PRIVATE$\PrivateQueueName
```

or

```
FORMATNAME:DIRECT=OS:pc.example.com\PRIVATE$\PrivateQueueName
```

See [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776346%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [John Breakwell's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/02/26/difference-between-path-name-and-format-name-when-accessing-msmq-queues.aspx) for more options.